# Make gif from png files in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, loops, gif

I have 5 images created with Matlab:

```
seabreeze_3.png
seabreeze_6.png
seabreeze_9.png
seabreeze_12.png
seabreeze_15.png
```

I want to create 1 gif file, showing the above images in chronological order using Matlab.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matla) is an example of how to create a gif with matlab.
This is the gist of the link: Append the images to the gif file in a loop

```
  % image 
  im = frame2im(frame); 
  [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); 
  % Write to the GIF File 
  if n == 1 
      imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf); 
  else 
      imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append'); 
  end
```